# Can you check multiple URLs in robotframework simulatenously?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

*I am editing my original question, hopefully this shows that I've done a bit more research*

I think I figured out one way to do it, however, I'm stuck on something, I figured out that I can use a `for loop` to iterate through a list of urls, my question is, for any following steps, such as `capture page screenshot` or `press key` etc where do I apply those? Do they get nested in the loop also?

I saw another stackoverflow post and it gave me this idea:

```
*** Variables ***
@{HOMEPAGES}     http://example.one    http://example.two   http://example.three
${BROWSER}      ff

*** Test Cases ***
test with several links
    :FOR    ${homepage}     IN      @{HOMEPAGES}
    \   open browser     ${homepage}
    \   capture page screenshot     ${homepage}
```

The example above gave me a PASS but I am wondering if I have to put every action inside the `for loop` if I want to apply those actions to the `@{HOMEPAGES}` array?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try it, and if you get stuck you can come back and ask a more soecific question.

Comment: Thank you. Just learning the framework. I'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: Just edited my question with a sample that I executed and verified. Also added a specific question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more or less standard ways of dealing with your task.
You can either use a [data-driven test](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style):

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template     Make Screenshots

*** Test Cases ***    Web Page
Page one              http://example.one
Page two              http://example.two
Page three            http://example.three

*** Keywords ***
Make Screenshots
  [Arguments]  ${homepage}
  Open Browser     ${homepage}    ff
  Capture Page Screenshot
```

Or simply use a custom keyword to group the required actions:

```
*** Variables ***
@{HOMEPAGES}     http://example.one    http://example.two    http://example.three
${BROWSER}      ff

*** Test Cases ***
test with several links
    :FOR    ${homepage}     IN      @{HOMEPAGES}
    \   Make Screenshots  ${homepage}

*** Keywords ***
Make Screenshots
  [Arguments]  ${homepage}
  Open Browser     ${homepage}    ${BROWSER}
  Capture Page Screenshot
```

Personally, I would go with a data-driven test because it's more elegant and easier to scale.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I ran a test with both examples and they both work as expected. I guess it comes down to preference in the end, thought data-driven does seem much more elegant as you put it. I will keep reading through the framework's documentation.